# Capturing a single page in an AEM package from a tree of pages

Tags: aem

Imagine you have a structure of pages called:

```
/content/site/en_us/foo/bar
```

You need to move the foo page from another environment to this one, but we don't want to include the bar page or any other children.

If I define a package with

```
/content/site/en_us/foo
```

it will capture the children, if I add an exclude of

```
/content/site/en_us/*.*
```

I will exclude the actual content of the page I'm trying to restore.

I could explicitly define an exclude for each child page, but in our case there are a rather large number of child pages for foo that makes this type of manual exclusion difficult.

Is there a way to capture just a page and it's contents and not child pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Content of the page is stored under the `jcr:content` node. We can use this fact to exclude everything except the content of this node:

```
<filter root="/content/site/en_us/foo">
    <exclude pattern=".*"/>
    <include pattern=".*/jcr:content.*"/>
</filter>
```

This filter definition will include the `foo` node, exclude all its descendants, except the `jcr:content` node and its subtree.

Comment: Thanks, my confusion occurred with relationship between the exclude and the include rules within the filter.

Comment: Yeah, it confuses me too, I need to check it in the Package Manager every time ;)

Comment: This answer is correct, although I'd like to note that the order of the rules make a difference. Perhaps that's what you meant with the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `/content/site/en_us/foo/jcr:content` directly.